# Bizarre error with rep() function in R

Tags: r

I'm runnig `rep()` function and passing an object as parameter to length.out argument

[image: Followig is the output]

```
# Initialization
pop.seq <- seq(0.05,0.95,by=0.1)

for(pop.rate in pop.seq){

# Population vector
pop.neg.count <- ((1-pop.rate)*100)
pop.vec <- c(rep(1,length.out=pop.rate*100),rep(0,length.out = pop.neg.count))

 # Loop 1's in split1
 for(split11.count in 1:(pop.rate*100)){
 # Loop 0's in split1
 for(split10.count in 0:(100-(pop.rate*100)-1)){
 # print values
    ---------
      --------
        ---------
    }
   }
 }
```

The above code would stop every time at 7th iteration &  pop.vec would have only 99 elements & following would give an output of 64 :
`length(rep(0,length.out = pop.neg.count))`

Also pop.neg.count shows value of 65 in the console.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in R version 3.2.2.

Comment: Could not replicate either. Does the error persist in a new/empty environment? I understand the purpose of the screenshot here, but could you also post the code in the future?

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that the value of `pop.neg.count` isn't actually 65.  For example,

```
R> pop.neg.count
[1] 65
R> length(rep(1, length.out=pop.neg.count))
[1] 64
```

However, when printing out the actual value, I get

```
R> sprintf("%f", pop.neg.count)
[1] "64.999999990"
```

At the start, I set

```
pop.neg.count = 64.99999999
```

Comment: I don't understand your example. If I set `pop.neg.count` to `64.99999`, R displays `64.99999`, not `65`. How do you get `65`?

Comment: @Pascal, maybe OP has `options(digits=2)` or something along those lines in their environment, that would display 65

Comment: I am not asking about the OP, but about your example.

Comment: @Pascal You can try `pop.neg.count <- 64.9999999999999`. With default settings, the variable output will be displayed as 65; but the error or the result described in the OP can be reproduced with such a value.

Comment: @RHertel Yes, I know this. But this is speculation on how OP set his R session.

Comment: @Pascal Sorry, I have `digits=4` in my `Rprofile. I'll update the answer to add a few more 9's.

Comment: I'm actually initializing pop.neg.count using seq() function like : po.range = seq(0.5,0.9,by=0.5) and then passing each elemnt to pop.range to pop.neg.count inside a loop

Comment: Interesting the error doesn't persist  on a new environment. But, as I have mentioned in the above comment, I'm initializing pop.neg.count inside a loop, and ever time the loop hits the 7th iteration, the error occurs

Comment: I tried using different initial value for the loop. Irrespective of this initial value, loop fails on 7th iteration!!

Comment: You have floating point errors.  You problem is the same as:  `sqrt(2)^2 == 2` giving you FALSE